# Adding a search function to a lookup column?

Tags: lookup-column

Situation:

- I have a **list** and a **library**.
- The list has a lookup column that allows you to **choose multiple documents** from the library.

Problem:

- The library has **several hundred documents**, so it's very difficult to find the right document(s) to add to the list item.

Is there any way I can implement a **search function** above the list of documents so the list **filters dynamically** as I start typing the beginning of the document reference?

I have yet to find a proper solution to this problem and I need to *avoid using SharePoint Designer* for maintenance reasons if at all possible.

Comment: What version of SharePoint? I just implemented PnP Search Webparts, they're awesome

Comment: I believe it's SharePoint Server 2016. Is PnP Search Webparts something I'd need to download?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your requirements can be met by the PnP Search modern webparts

```
https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts
```

For your situation, I would create a new page with these Search web parts configured with a custom Result Source pointing to the Document library. If you go into site settings => Search Result Sources => New Result Source => Launch Query Builder. You can create a source that points to the Document Library

```
{searchTerms} path:https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/Shared%20Documents -ContentTypeId:0x0120* -ContentClass:STS_List_* -FileExtension:aspx
```

Once you click save, go back into the new Result source and copy the GUID from the URL. You can then paste this GUID into the 'Result Source Identifier' in your Search Verticals webpart

[image]

You'll have to add 'Search Box', 'Search Verticals' and 'Search Results' for this to work

[image]